# Flutter / l10n with dynamic parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

How to use l10n with dynamic parameters?
like this.

AppLocalizations.of(context)!['dynamic_string'];
=> Try defining the operator '[]'.

But the class is generated automatically so overwrite with each build.
Thx , If anyone has a solution.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by providing a placeholder in the .arb file like so:

```
"weekTitle": "Week {weekNumber}",
"@weekTitle": {
    "placeholders": {
        "weekNumber": {
            "type": "int"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can call it like this:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).weekTitle(_calendarWeek)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. And should not. What is the chance that a random value is actually in your resources?

You can always branch depending on decisions in your program:

```
isUsersFirstLogin ? AppLocalizations.of(context)!.Hello 
                  : AppLocalizations.of(context)!.HelloAgain
```

---

If you absolutely need this feature of addressing random dynamic resources that are magically correct, there is a alternative solution described here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#alternative-internationalization-workflows

Comment: Thank you ,but Sadness... :)